# How to Create a floating data stream Image like this?

Tags: inkscape, vector

I'm working on a project and I need to create a vector image that includes a laptop, a man, and a representation of floating data streams. I have a basic idea of what I want it to look like, but I'm not sure how to create it using Inkscape.

**1. Efforts Made**: I've started by sketching out my concept and experimenting with basic shapes in Inkscape.

**2. Challenges**: My main challenge is creating a Sankey chart-like representation of data streams flowing between a laptop and a man within my vector design.

**3. Consideration of Purchasing**: While I could purchase an existing vector image, I have specific customizations and stylistic preferences in mind that may not be available in pre-made vectors.

**4. Goal**: I aim to create a vector image that balances stylized, illustrative elements with a touch of realism to convey a person interacting with technology and data flows effectively.

**5. Experience**: I'm relatively new to vector design but am eager to learn and improve my skills in Inkscape.

Here's a sample image of the image I'm aiming to create:

[image]

Comment: have you checked sankey charts? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sankey+chart&atb=v328-1&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: What have you tired? Where is that failing? Why can't you merely purchase the image in the question? Are you intending to essentially *redraw* that image as vector? Is the goal photo-realistic recreation as vector or a more stylistic *illustrative* image? Are you experienced in vector creation?

Comment: The image example is a raster image, a photograph overlaid with some artwork, and so Inkscape is not really suited for work like this. It can't really edit raster images. Vectors are also generally very sharp images, unlike the overlay which fades out and is slightly blurry/glowing.  It would be better to use GIMP to do photo manipulation work like this.  You could perhaps create the graphic in Inkscape, import and combine with a photo in GIMP, apply blurs/layer masks with gradients to make a finished composition.

Comment: @Scott cant type all of that in here . refer to > https://justpaste.it/akh3x

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks. but i dont know how to make the illustration of sankey chart.

Comment: As a **vector** image, this would be challenging for an experienced user. I am not certain *any* type of basic photorealism in vector form is a reachable goal for an inexperienced user. I'd love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: The floating part is not an image of any real world data stream shown by some advanced visualization  program. An artist has imagined it and it presents some data and its streaming as much as all tricky gadgets shown in a science fiction movie present the real and working instrumentation of a spacecraft in year 3000. You can well draw the floating items as flat and without effects in Inkscape, but matching the colors, perspective, transparency and that dreamy glow (that's Blur) with an underlying image is very difficult in Inkscape. Warning: Making a drawn copy of a stock photo is copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's too much here to create a full tutorial, but here are the basics of how you could begin to create such a diagram. This is for Inkscape 1.3.  Note that I assume a basic familiarity with Inkscape here, and this may not be suitable for a raw beginner. Might be better to do some basic youtube tutorials first.

1. Using the Pen tool <kbd>B</kbd> draw a curved line with a stroke and no fill.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to Duplicate, then wwitch off all snapping
3. Select with the Selector Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, and move down while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the move vertically
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat the transform many times
5. Select all, and switch to the Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>
6. Click and drag to make a selection of all the nodes on the right edge
7. Open the Align & Distribute panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
8. Under the Align tab, Set the Align Nodes realtive to: *Middle of Selection*, and hit the button that looks like this [image: first button] to "Align selected nodes to a common horizonal line"
9. Click and drag to select all the nodes which come to a point, and you can click and drag to move it freely.

Here's a screen capture

[image]

You can then delete some paths to make it look kind of random

[image]

For the rest, group the result after step 9 above, duplicate two times, change each group to different stroke colours. Adjust the point at which the nodes come to a point using the same techniques shown above in step 9. Groups will help you to arrange/organise everything.  Here's an example created using the above technique. In the end I set each Group's blending mode to Lighten. Displayed over a black background

[image]